# Windows Forms: ComboBoxColumn in DataGridView with different data sources

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView in a Windows Form bound to a data source. I need to fill a ComboBoxColumn depending on the value of some of the columns. In WebForms we have a `RowDataBound` event that we can use to fill the combos, but I can't find something similar in WinForms.

I have seen some people suggesting `CellValueChanged` event but, in my case, the user is not allowed to edit the columns, he can just select a value in the combobox.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I'll give you a little guidance, though I've long ago forgotten the specific implementation. You can't have different datasources for a combobox column, but you can apply a filtered dataview so it appears to have different data. That means you must have all the available values for any row in the combobox's data source. You could use the EditingControlShowing event to look at the other cell, and apply a filtered DataView to the combobox.

Comment: If this is about more than just filtering: You can have individual datasources for individual cells (not columns).